# Php foreach loop syntax

Tags: php

Trying to check a list. Need some help with the foreach loop. Can't seem to understand the documentation for it.

```
  foreach ($i = 0; $i <= $List; $i++)
     {
         foreach($ii = 0; $ii2 <= $List 2; ii++)
         {

          }
        // something
     }
```

Comment: what is your desired result? what i `$List`? it it an array? what are you trying to use the second loop for?

Comment: it's nested loop and awful variable naming

Comment: The issue is your `$List 2` which is invalid. Question is what you try to express by that...

Comment: Apart from that you should explain _what_ it is in the documentation you do not understand.

Comment: are you sure you read [php.net domumention](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)?

Comment: Oh, and... there is a difference between a `for` loop and a `foreach` loop... You mix both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-php-foreach-actually-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a correct `foreach` syntax. Use `for` loop instead.

```
$a = array("marx","engels","lenin","stalin","mao zedong");
$a_size = count($a);
for($i=0; $i<$a_size; $i++) {
  echo $a[$i];
}
```

Foreach usage.

```
$comrades = array("marx","engels","lenin","stalin","mao zedong");
foreach($comrades as $comrade) {
  echo "Comrade ".$comrade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats not a foreach loop, thats a for-loop with syntax error. That would be a right `FOR-Loop`:

```
foreach ($i = 0; $i <= $List; $i++) {
    foreach($a = 0; $a <= $List2; a++) { // You can't have a whitespace between "List and 2"
        // Do something inside inner loop
    }
    // Staff in outer loop      
}
```

http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.for.php

If you wan't a foreach-loop:

```
foreach($your_array as $element) {
    // This loop is going to be executed for each element of your array. You can access the actual value by $element
}
```

http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0 // defines starting value
$i <= $List // condition (while true loop goes on)
$i++ // change of the loop variable that at some point will end the loop
```

inside this loop is nested loop
I guess in nested loop it should be "$List"2 not "$List 2"

Comment: and that should be for loop not foreach, because foreach has different syntax